# Android Email Intent and Linebreaks Howto?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, line-breaks

I have the following problem:

I am sending an email via an intent and in the email I want to have linebreaks.

When I try "setType('text/plain')" and use \n's the Email-App doesn't use these, but the Gmail-App is OK.
When I set "setType('text/html')" and use br's and Html.fromHtml(emailtext), the Email-app doesn't do line breaks. When I am not using Html.fromHtml(emailtext) the Email-app makes linebreaks, but the Gmail-App displays the br's as normal text.

Isn't there a way to do simple linebreaks in Android email intents?

Answer (score 0):

**hi, may b this code will help u out**

```
String emailMessage = "<html><body><div align='left'><p>I found this information on Actor Genie and wanted to share it with you.</p><p><b>Feature </b>: "
                        + filmName
                        + "</p><p><b>Casting Director</b>: "
                        + casting
                        + "</p><p><b>Distributor</b>: "
                        + distributor
                        + "<p><b>Story Line</b>: "
                        + storyLine
                        + "</p><p>For up to the date casting info get <a href='http://www.actorgenie.com/'>Actor Genie</a></p></div></body></html>";
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                // emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        emailSubject);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html
                        .fromHtml(emailMessage));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                finish();
```

Comment: No, that didn't change anything. That's basically what I am doing, I just didn't have these html+body parts. It seems that when I do a Html.fromHtml the Email-app doesn't use this html-tags anymore. By the way, it's a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: its working for me n i tested it in samsung ace and HTC Desire

Answer (score 0):

Force Gmail by this

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
                     "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Use \n in your text code.

```
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello \n World");
```

Comment: I don't want to force gmail. It's for a business app, so people should be allowed to use whatever email client they want.